# Does JAXB support modification of existing XML documents without marshalling/unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to keep comments, ordering, etc. in the document and edit the document in-place using a Java interface.

Does JAXB do this?

Do other tools such as XMLBeans do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the JAXB [`Binder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html) for this use case:

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_1/>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <!-- COMMENT #1 -->
    <address>
        <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_2/>
        <street>1 A Street</street>
        <!-- COMMENT #2 -->
        <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_3/>
        <city>Any Town</city>
    </address>
    <!-- COMMENT #3 -->
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_4/>
    <phone-number type="home">555-HOME</phone-number>
    <!-- COMMENT #4 -->
    <phone-number type="cell">555-CELL</phone-number>
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_5/>
    <!-- COMMENT #5 -->
</customer>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class BinderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Document document = db.parse(xml);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
        Customer customer = (Customer) binder.unmarshal(document);
        customer.getAddress().setStreet("2 NEW STREET");
        PhoneNumber workPhone = new PhoneNumber();
        workPhone.setType("work");
        workPhone.setValue("555-WORK");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(workPhone);
        binder.updateXML(customer);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }     
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<customer>
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_1/>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <!-- COMMENT #1 -->
    <address>
        <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_2/>
        <street>2 NEW STREET</street>
        <!-- COMMENT #2 -->
        <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_3/>
        <city>Any Town</city>
    </address>
    <!-- COMMENT #3 -->
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_4/>
    <phone-number type="home">555-HOME</phone-number>
    <!-- COMMENT #4 -->
    <phone-number type="cell">555-CELL</phone-number>
    <phone-number type="work">555-WORK</phone-number>
    <UNMAPPED_ELEMENT_5/>
    <!-- COMMENT #5 -->
</customer>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html

Comment: Strangely the new binder code is not working for me even though it's almost exactly like my previous, working unmarshalling code. This is the old working code which works great: `File xmlFile = ...
File xmlSchema = ...
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Process.class);       
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xmlSchema);
Process process = (Process) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);`

Comment: This is the new code:`DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();                
Document document = db.parse(xmlFile);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Process.class);
Binder<Node> binder = jaxbContext.createBinder();
binder.setSchema(SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xmlSchema);
Process process = (Process) binder.unmarshal(document);`

Comment: The new code throws:`javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'process'.]` Yet they look almost exactly the same to me. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @jonas789 - You may need to set your DocumentBuilderFactory to be namespace aware:  dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Thanks again. The only thing not working is comments aren't kept. The blog post you link to suggests to use the EclipseLink implementation instead of the standard JDK one so I'll try that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any reputation so I can't upvote. By the way, Stackoverflow should allow answer providers to link PayPal accounts for donations.

Comment: @jonas789 - you could always click the check box next to the answer to mark it as "accepted", this gives both of us some rep points.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help. More importantly, thanks for MOXy. The JDK impl. didn't keep the comments.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that there is no way to have the default JDK JAXB implementation (Metro) keep the comments, etc.? In other words, is this a case where MOXy works and Metro is broken or a case where the given code is not enough to keep comments, etc. with Metro but that can be achieved with other code?

Comment: @jonas789 - You may always want to ask your last question on:  http://www.java.net/forums/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb

Comment: For anyone else who reads this later, I did ask the question on the java.net metro-and-jaxb forum and there was no response (this is now a few days later). The forum looks like a ghost town.