# How to maintain entry order information with JAXB?

Tags: jaxb

Let's say I have an XML file like the following

```
    <root>
      <record>foo</record>
      <record>bar</record>
    </root>
```

I use JAXB to read in the record. Does JAXB keep the information of say `bar` comes before `foo`?

My gut feeling is NO, JAXB does not maintain this information. But then I am stuck since I actually need to get this information... Any recommendation... BTW, I can't change the format of the xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually tried it?

JAXB's [`@XmlType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation as a [`propOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#propOrder()) property which defines the order of properties.

So you can do:

```
@XmlRootElemen(name="root")
@XmlType(propOrder={"record2", "record1"})
public class Root {

  public String record1;
  public String record2;

}
```

**Update**

The OP has edited his original XML from this:

```
<root>
  <record2>
  <record1>
</root>
```

To this:

```
<root>
  <record>foo</record>
  <record>bar</record>
</root>
```

My answer applies to the original XML with two elements `record2` and `record1`.

Comment: Someone changed my original question, both foo and bar belong to the SAME <record> but how do I know "bar" comes before "foo" ??? Thanks

Comment: @user2167013 I have edited your question and only corrected the markup on `<record2>` -> `<record2>foo</record2>`. Now you have changed BOTH to `<record .../>` which is a completely different question. Now it looks like my anwer, which was correct for the original question, is wrong. Sorry, this is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

## Order & Repeated Elements

If your XML is like the following:

```xml
<root>
  <record>foo</record>
  <record>bar</record>
</root>
```

If you map a repeating element to a `java.util.List` the order of the elements will be maintained in the `List`.

```java
@XmlElement(name="record")
public List<String> getRecords() {
    return records;
}
```

## Order & Non-Repeated Elements

If on the other hand your XML is like the following:

```xml
<root>
  <hello>foo</hello>
  <world>bar</world>
</root>
```

### Using Marshaller

Then using `Marshaller` the order in which the elements are marshalled to XML will be controlled by:

- The `propOrder` property on the `@XmlType` annotation.
- The `@XmlAccessorOrder` annotation

### Using Binder

Using `Binder` you parse your XML into a DOM and use Binder to unmarshal that.  Then you can make changes to your object and apply those changes back to the DOM.  This allows you to preserve aspects such as ordering from the orginal XML

- [Does JAXB support modification of existing XML documents without marshalling/unmarshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059575/does-jaxb-support-modification-of-existing-xml-documents-without-marshalling-unm/6059672#6059672)

Comment: The problem is JAXB reads the xml and populates its data structure. The ordering information is already lost there. How do I use the java.util.List to map? Sorry, I think I am missing something.

Comment: @user2167013 - What do you mean the ordering is lost?  A `java.util.List` maintains order.